How to Disable or Suppress "xdg-open" Popup in Puppeteer (Node.js, Alpine Linux)?
I'm currently developing an API that uses Puppeteer within a Docker container based on the node:18-alpine image. I'm facing an issue where, with certain links, Chromium triggers an "xdg-open" popup, which I cannot handle or suppress through my code. This popup prompts the user to open an external application and interrupts the automated process I'm trying to achieve with Puppeteer.

What I’ve Tried:

Uninstalling xdg-utils: I attempted to remove xdg-utils and all associated files from the container, hoping this would prevent the popup from appearing. Unfortunately, this did not work, and the popup still appears.
Exploring Chromium Flags: I’ve looked into Chromium flags that might suppress external application prompts, but I haven’t found anything that directly addresses the "xdg-open" behavior.
Puppeteer Options: I've also tried tweaking various Puppeteer launch options like --no-sandbox, --disable-popup-blocking, and --disable-dev-shm-usage, but these don't seem to impact the xdg-open popup.


Can you provide full context and a [mcve] of the code that triggers this?
